# Visualize Decision Boundary on High Dimensional Data Set

Tags: classification, data-visualization, dimensionality-reduction

Inspired by this beautiful visualization on [decision boundary/surface](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_classifier_comparison.html) of each classifier in the sklearn documentation, it really helps to understand how each classifier works and what dataset does the classifier work the best. Unfortunately, real-world data almost always has dimension higher than two and human perception almost understand three dimensions.

What are the ways to visualize the decision boundary after dimension reduction for a dataset, for example, PCA and t-SEN? How to think about the reduction of high dimension decision "cube/space" to a plane in 3D or a line in 2D? Is there a particular dimension reduction technique works better for the purpose?